# Is the toolbar item separator deprecated in Lion?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nstoolbaritem

Whenever I add a separator toolbar item to my toolbar and run my application, it's not present. Is it deprecated in Lion?

Interface Builder:
[image]

Application when ran:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as well as the customise toolbar item

Comment: Do you know _why_ these two were deprecated, and if they were replaced by something else that we should be using instead?

Comment: I'd assume stylistic purposes. You should be using menu items for customise and spaces for dividers instead

Comment: Maybe due to lack of support in auto layout.